# Android Emulator cant start without internet connection

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio, emulation

Hey guys I've just installed Android Studio on **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**, and I have all the needed Sdks and other accessories I think needs to be installed. 
I can run the emulator whenever I've an Internet connection, but if I disconnect the Internet and try to run the emulator, I get this error message:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
qemu-system-i386: it seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting
WARNING: unable to configure any DNS servers, name resolution will not work
```

Someone suggested I do this: "ifconfig lo up" but whenever I do that nothing change, and I still get the same error when running the emulator offline.

Can you guys please help me.

Comment: Maybe the emulator just *needs* an internet connection to run - impossible without that.

Comment: hmm..... I dont think so, because I did run android studio on Ubuntu before and everything work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a way around this after sleepless nights of trials and errors. All I had to do was to turn off **WIFI** and disable **networking**, and then the emulator started when I ran it. Don't know if this is a temporary fix, but I have my emulator working perfectly for now. Hope this helps others in similar situation.